# CeleryCAM not working... - Django/Celery

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, celery

celery works wonderfully! :) e.g. results are returned with no problems!

---

**Unfortunately celerycam does not:**

This is what my panel looks like, celeryev looks the same.

**NB: all those tasks have been completed succesfully, they are just not showing as completed, and the names are not showing either.**

[image]

---

I'm usingthe following commands:

> python manage.py celeryd -l info -E
>
> python manage.py celerycam

My BROKER is **RabbitMQ**

My DATABASE is **MongoDB**

Django, Celery and RabbitMQ are running on a clean Ubuntu 10 install.

---

Any ideas folks? Would be amazing if someone could help me on this one :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only run one monitor at a time (this is changing in the next version, 2.2).  Make sure you don't have any left over celerycam/celeryev processes running, or upgrade to the development version (it is in freeze now, and is already well tested).